# Root path analogue in uWSGI as in Uvicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi, uvicorn

**Uvicorn** has the option `--root-path` (https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#http) that helps a lot if the application is mounted to a specific path, distinct to `/`. For example, in case of a Django application I can run it with:

```
uvicorn myproj.asgi:application --host=localhost --port=8001 --root-path="/myproj-custom-path"
```

So if I configure the Nginx location `/myproj-custom-path/` as `proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/`, I can access the application by `http://localhost:80/myproj-custom-path` with all the functionality, including the Admin panel, without the need to specify the root path anywhere else in the project.

Is there a similar option or a way to do the same with **uWSGI**?